# Whats the difference between parser and view call? How to retrive the data from the view? (pass, return)

Tags: php, codeigniter, html-parsing, codeigniter-2

1. What's the difference between these two calls? What's the general difference between parse and view? When do I use parser->parse and when load->view?

   ```
   $this->load->view('content', $data);
   $this->parser->parse('content', $data, FALSE);
   ```
2. If I have this array:

   ```
   $data = array(
      'title' => 'Home Page',
      'heading' => 'Heading'
   );
   $this->parser->parse('content', $data, FALSE);
   ```

   In content.php view I can do both by calling parse function

   ```
   echo $title;
   echo '<h1>{heading}</h1>';
   ```

   what's the difference?
3. As I understand The 3rd paramether of parse function can be TRUE or FALSE, when it's TRUE I can get values from the view like this

   ```
   $string = $this->parser->parse('content',$data, TRUE);
   ```

   how can I do that, what's the code in content?

Answer (score 4):

`load->view()` does exactly what it says, it loads a view page.

`parser->parse` parses the page and can be used with views that contain template variables in place of PHP variables.

In application, both functions accomplish the objective of loading a view that contains HTML and PHP variables or template placeholders. However, parse is going to have more overhead, as it is not a native PHP solution, and is parsed to replace the templating values.

Consult the doumentation for more information:

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/parser.html